# JBoss migration from JBoss AS 4.2 GA to JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-4.2.x

Any one done migration from JBoss AS 4.2 GA to JBoss EAP 6.2?

1. Does JBoss EAP 6.2 has web and app server..? In JBoss AS 4.2 GA has the folder structure /server/app and /server/web where as in JBoss EAP 6.2 no server folder at all.
2. How to deploy the services in web and app in JBoss EAP 6.2?
3. Gone through the system migration guide, have to change the packaging structure of EAR or WAR due to change of modular class loading.
4. Where/how to find the system dependencies, user dependencies, local resources and inter-deployment dependencies in JBoss AS 4.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JBoss 7 / EAP 6 is nearly 100% different, so there is no speaking of "migration". You will have to start from scratch; learning how the AS works, how to configure stuff (which is much easier to be honest and very well documented on the JBoss site) and to get the deployment of your application working. Which might be a very hairy thing to do if you have legacy tech such as Seam 2.

Luckily JBoss 7 is also quite nicely documented so guess what? There is actually some form of a guide. For JBoss 5 and up though, but it should still be helpful.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Windup project](https://github.com/windup/windup).
It is the official JBoss project to support (semi)automated migration. There are no rules for 4.2 yet, the current set of rules covers a subset of migration knowledge.