# How to migrate: JBoss AS 7.1.1 -> JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7, server-migration

I'm looking for guides regarding specific details / instructions to migrate our app.

The closest I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756059/jboss-migration-from-jboss-as-4-2-ga-to-jboss-eap-6-2).
But that is about AS 4.2 GA to EAP 6.2.

Can anyone guide my poor soul? Please help.

Comment: Have you just tried it to see what happens?

Comment: I think the linked question explains about AS 4.2 -> AS 7, and THEN AS 7 -> EAP. For our case, we dont need to do the 1st part. and its the 2nd part thats challenging.

Comment: What we tried is directly putting our app into EAP7. There were a few errors, and were still investigating on it separately. It would be really helpful if there was a direct guide on this, thats why Im asking anyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell if this is an "answer". But just leaving this here in case somebody needs it.

We've now successfully ported our app with no errors. What fixed our problem was just properly adding our machine's hostname in /etc/hosts.

In our case, there were no other "porting-specific" files to change. Its either our app didnt use very complex features, or I think maybe AS 7 -> EAP 7 is just a direct port?

Anyways, cheers :D